# summation of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{n^{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Let $x\in (0,1)$ and $n\in 2\mathbb{N}+1$ be fixed. the series
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x^{n^{k}}}$$
is convergent by Ratio Test. what is the sum of the series ?

Answer (score 4):

These are well-known examples in lacunary series: generalized to allow  complex $x$, they are analytic functions on the unit disk $|x|<1$ for which the unit circle is a natural boundary.  However, I'm not aware of a "standard" notation for them.  There is certainly no closed-form expression for the sum in terms of "elementary" functions.